# find max/min value in dictionary values in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using VBA to store key and value associated with the key into dictionary.

```
Sub Dict_Example()

Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For i = 1 to 5
    dict.Add i, some number
Next i
```

I would like to find the highest value and its associated key in `dict`.

For example, if dict = {1: 5, 2: 10, 3: 6, 4: 11, 5: 3} where 1,2,3,4,5 are keys and 5, 10, 6, 11, 3 are values then it should return 4:11.

How do I do this in VBA?

Comment: See: https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/#Sorting_by_values

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would generate an array from the `dict.items` and use Max/Min function on that. Then loop keys and compare items against that.

```
Option Explicit    
Public Sub Dict_Example()
    Dim dict As Object, max As Long, min As Long, arr(), key As Variant, i As Long
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For i = 1 To 5
        dict.Add i, i * Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 100)
    Next i

    max = Application.max(dict.items)
    min = Application.min(dict.items)

    For Each key In dict
        Debug.Print key, dict(key)
        If dict(key) = max Then Debug.Print "max= " & dict(key) & vbTab & "key= " & key
    Next
    Stop
End Sub
```

Comment: _+1_ Didn't know you could use `.min` and `.max` like that, I'll be tucking that away in my brain for future use.

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this by using a couple arrays to temporarily store your high and low values and associated keys as you iterated through the dictionary like this:

```
Sub test()
Dim dict As New Dictionary
Dim low(1 To 2)
Dim high(1 To 2)
Dim i As Long
Dim key

For i = 1 To 5
    dict.Add i, 'some number
Next i

low(1) = dict.Keys(0)
low(2) = dict(dict.Keys(0))
high(1) = dict.Keys(0)
high(2) = dict(dict.Keys(0))

For i = 0 To dict.Count - 1
    If dict(dict.Keys(i)) < low(2) Then
        low(1) = dict.Keys(i)
        low(2) = dict(dict.Keys(i))
    ElseIf dict(dict.Keys(i)) > high(2) Then
        high(1) = dict.Keys(i)
        high(2) = dict(dict.Keys(i))
    End If
Next i

Debug.Print low(1) & ":" & low(2) & vbCrLf & high(1) & ":" & high(2)

End Sub
```

But sorting like this would only work correctly for numeric values. @Ryan Wildry's comment is the way to go for generally sorting a dictionary, then you would grab your values using `dict(dict.Keys(0))` and `dict(dict.Keys(dict.Count - 1))` respectively where `dict` references your sorted dictionary.

**EDIT:**

You'll need to [add a library reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/how-to/check-or-add-an-object-library-reference) to the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` for this to work.